# java - Unparseable date when using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to read data from RSS feeds and one of the fields is when the feed was last updated.
I'm using something similar to this:

```
Date date;
String output;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;

String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM, HH:mm:ss Z";

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
date = formatter.parse("Wed, 25 Mar 2020 08:00:00 +0200");
output = date.toString();
System.out.println(pattern + " | " + output);
```

but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 25 Mar 2020 08:00:00 +0200"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:16)
```

Comment: The string you are trying to parse does not match the format string. The year `yyyy` is missing in the format string. There is also a comma after the month which is not in your input string. Try this: `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

java.time is the modern java date and time API and has a built-in formatter for your string:

```
    String lastUpdatedString = "Wed, 25 Mar 2020 08:00:00 +0200";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime
            .parse(lastUpdatedString, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2020-03-25T08:00+02:00

So there’s no need to write our own format pattern string, which is always error-prone, and certainly no need to use the `SimpleDateFormat` class. That class is a notoriously troublemaker of a class, so we had wanted to avoid it anyway.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.